# How different combinations of morphisms are represented in arrow category?

Tags: category-theory

According to the definition of arrow category at nlab website, if category C has $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1$ as objects and following morphisms:

$a:a_0 \rightarrow a_1$
$b:b_0 \rightarrow b_1$
$f:a_0 \rightarrow b_0$
$g:a_1 \rightarrow b_1$

then the arrow category Arr(C) will have the following morphism:

$<f,g>: <a_0,a,a_1> \rightarrow <b_0,b,b_1>$

But what would happen if instead we had following morphisms in C:

$a:a_0 \rightarrow a_1$
$b:b_0 \rightarrow b_1$
$f:a_0 \rightarrow b_0$

or if having following:

$a:a_0 \rightarrow a_1$
$b:b_0 \rightarrow b_1$
$f:a_0 \rightarrow b_0$
$g:b_1 \rightarrow a_1$

How would those setups be represented in arrow category?

Comment: Your first statement is wrong as it is, it depends on the composition in $C$. The morphism $\langle f,g\rangle$ you describe exists in $\mathrm{Arr}(C)$ if and only if $bf=ga$ in $C$.

Comment: @Pece Got it. Thank you very much.